# Matplotlib how to add rounded edges in figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I want to create the same visualization as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puzdn.png) and I obtained this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctGId.png) which is already super good but I'm trying to figure out how can I make rounded edges in my figure (the grey section)?
I already tried to find a way with Fancybox without success. I also tried seaborn library but couldn't get the same barplot results + corresponding custom text.
If someone has an idea? Thank you very much.
Here's the code I'm using :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Commun parameters
day_of_week = final_result_table[final_result_table['s__platform'] == 'Android']['day_text'].values[0]

import matplotlib.font_manager #To change the font name
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects #For Title-text shadow


#Test dataset
test_acquisition = pd.DataFrame({
    "iOS":[15222,750],    
    "Android":[18752, 1520]
    }, index=["dau", "nb_downloads"]
)

#Test data
nb_downloads = test_acquisition.iloc[1,0] + test_acquisition.iloc[1,1]
nb_downloads_var = (final_result_table[final_result_table['s__platform'] == 'Android']['WoW_var_nb_downloads'].values[0])                  

nb_players = test_acquisition.iloc[0,0] + test_acquisition.iloc[0,1]
nb_players_var = (final_result_table[final_result_table['s__platform'] == 'Android']['WoW_var_dau'].values[0])  


#Create bar plots
acquisition = test_acquisition.apply(lambda x: x*100/sum(x), axis=1)
acquisition.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True, color=['#7ae04a', '#f7a059'], legend=None)


#Add dynamic and custom text
#For downloads
plt.text(57, 1, '%s Downloads'%nb_downloads, ha="right", va="center", fontsize=15)
if nb_downloads_var > 0:  
    plt.text(59, 0.96, '%s'%nb_downloads_var, ha="left", va="center", fontsize=10, fontstyle='italic', color='green' )
else:
    plt.text(59, 0.96, '%s'%nb_downloads_var, ha="left", va="center", fontsize=10,  fontstyle='italic', color='red' )
plt.text(67, 0.96, 'Last %s'%day_of_week, ha="left", va="center", fontsize=10, fontstyle='italic')    


#For DAU
plt.text(57, 0, '%s Players'%nb_players, ha="right", va="center", fontsize=15)
if nb_players_var > 0:  
    plt.text(59, -0.04, '%s'%nb_players_var, ha="left", va="center", fontsize=10, fontstyle='italic', color='green' )
else:
    plt.text(59, -0.04, '%s'%nb_players_var, ha="left", va="center", fontsize=10,  fontstyle='italic', color='red' )
plt.text(67, -0.04, 'Last %s'%day_of_week, ha="left", va="center", fontsize=10, fontstyle='italic')    

#Customize figure
plt.title("ACQUISITION", fontsize=30, fontname='Liberation Sans Narrow', path_effects=[path_effects.withSimplePatchShadow()])
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = '#dbdbd9'
plt.axis('off')
#plt.savefig('acquisition.png')
```